# error with python thread

Tags: python, python-2.7, tweepy

I try to use `thread` in my script but i get this error:

> Unhandled exception in thread started by sys.excepthook is missing
>   lost sys.stderr

My script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tweepy
import thread

consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""
access_key = ""
access_secret = ""


def deleteThread(api, objectId):
    try:
        api.destroy_status(objectId)
        print "Deleted:", objectId
    except:
        print "Failed to delete:", objectId

def oauth_login(consumer_key, consumer_secret):
    """Authenticate with twitter using OAuth"""

    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth_url = auth.get_authorization_url()

    verify_code = raw_input("Authenticate at %s and then enter you verification code here > " % auth_url) 
    auth.get_access_token(verify_code)

    return tweepy.API(auth)

def batch_delete(api):
    print "You are about to Delete all tweets from the account @%s." % api.verify_credentials().screen_name
    print "Does this sound ok? There is no undo! Type yes to carry out this action."
    do_delete = raw_input("> ")
    if do_delete.lower() == 'yes':
        for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline).items():
            try:
                thread.start_new_thread( deleteThread, (api, status.id, ) )
            except:
                print "Failed to delete:", status.id

if __name__ == "__main__":
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    print "Authenticated as: %s" % api.me().screen_name

    batch_delete(api)
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Any reason why you are using `thread` instead of `threading`?

Comment: @cdarke No, i just try to learn and use python thread.

Comment: I think your problem is that you don't wait for the threads to complete and the error is raised as the interpreter tries to exit while threads are still running. Your sleep just gives your threads more time to exit. But it also slows everything down. If you move to the `threading` module, it waits for its threads to exit (unless they are also set daemon).

Comment: Another thing to consider if learning python. The language forked some time ago and the future is python 3, not python 2. Update to version 3 and you'll find that the `thread` module is gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

> I just solve my problem by adding `time.sleep(1)` before
>
> `thread.start_new_thread( deleteThread, (api, status.id, ) )`